# How to load viewController when user tap on notification in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I have done push notification using FCM on the app side. When the user taps on the notification it navigates to specific viewController from the app side to custom SDK. I have tried many ways but viewController is not showing but all functionalities are loaded successfully.

**1. First attempt:** [Notification tap is detected and passed data from the app side to framework. Loaded particular viewController functionalities but viewController are not showing.]

When user tap notification from the app side, it will send data to the framework to show a particular viewController.

here is the code for the app side:

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    
    
    
    if(application.applicationState == .active){
      print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("didReceive notification tapped",userInfo)

        TaskName = userInfo[taskName] as? String ?? ""
        print("TaskName::::", TaskName ?? "")
        ProcessInstanceId = userInfo[processInstanceId] as? String ?? ""
        print("ProcessInstanceId::::", ProcessInstanceId ?? "")
        processDefinitionName = userInfo[ProcessDefinitionId] as? String ?? ""
        print("processDefinitionName::::", processDefinitionName ?? "")
        TaskID = userInfo[taskId] as? String ?? ""
        print("taskID::::", TaskID ?? "")
        FormKey = userInfo[formKey] as? String ?? ""
        print("FormKey::::", FormKey ?? "")
        Types = userInfo[type] as? String ?? ""
        print("Type::::", Types ?? "")
        Title = userInfo[title] as? String ?? ""
        print("Title::::", Title ?? "")
        Body = userInfo[body] as? String ?? ""
        print("Body::::", Body ?? "")
        CreatedDate = userInfo[created] as? String ?? ""
        print("created:::", CreatedDate ?? "")




        AFlowBuilder(self).callFormView(taskName: TaskName ?? "", processInstanceID: ProcessInstanceId ?? "", ProcessDefinitionName: processDefinitionName ?? "", taskId: TaskID ?? "", formKey: FormKey ?? "", title: Title ?? "", type: Types ?? "", body: Body ?? "", created: CreatedDate ?? "", formStatus: false)


    }
    completionHandler()
    
    
  }
```

Here is the code from the framework side:

```
  private var taskViewNew: UIViewController?

    public func callFormView(taskName: String, processInstanceID: String, ProcessDefinitionName: String, taskId: String, formKey: String, title: String, type: String, body: String, created: String, formStatus: Bool){
    

    
    let newNotification = makeSaveNotification(taskName: taskName, processInstanceID: processInstanceID, ProcessDefinitionName: ProcessDefinitionName, taskId: taskId, formKey: formKey, title: title, type: type, body: body, created: created, formStatus: formStatus)
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    //        let realmData = realm.objects(NotificationRealmModel.self).filter("name = \(userNameRealm ?? "")").first!

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(newNotification)
                print("ream notification saved path url:: call form view", realm.configuration.fileURL ?? "")



}

                    let controller = CreateCardViewController()
    
                    let str = formKey
                    let result = String(str.dropFirst(7))
                    print(result)
                    let s = String(result.dropLast(10))
                    print("newFormKey call form view", s )
                    let v = convap(text: s)
                    controller.processInstanceId = processInstanceID
                    controller.cardName = ""
                    controller.TaskIdValue = taskId
                    controller.formKey = v
                    controller.tabName = "NotificationTapped"
                    controller.fullFormKey = formKey
                    
                
                    self.taskViewNew?.addChild(controller)
                    self.taskViewNew?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
                    controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

  //                        controller.didMove(toParent: taskViewNew)
                    taskViewNew?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    
                    

}
```

2. Second attempt: [Notification detected in the app side and passed value to viewController. And, Inside viewController framework method is called to load framework viewController but all functionality is loaded successfully but the view is not loaded]

Here is the code from the app side:

```
       func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    
    
    
    if(application.applicationState == .active){
      print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("didReceive notification tapped",userInfo)

        TaskName = userInfo[taskName] as? String ?? ""
        print("TaskName::::", TaskName ?? "")
        ProcessInstanceId = userInfo[processInstanceId] as? String ?? ""
        print("ProcessInstanceId::::", ProcessInstanceId ?? "")
        processDefinitionName = userInfo[ProcessDefinitionId] as? String ?? ""
        print("processDefinitionName::::", processDefinitionName ?? "")
        TaskID = userInfo[taskId] as? String ?? ""
        print("taskID::::", TaskID ?? "")
        FormKey = userInfo[formKey] as? String ?? ""
        print("FormKey::::", FormKey ?? "")
        Types = userInfo[type] as? String ?? ""
        print("Type::::", Types ?? "")
        Title = userInfo[title] as? String ?? ""
        print("Title::::", Title ?? "")
        Body = userInfo[body] as? String ?? ""
        print("Body::::", Body ?? "")
        CreatedDate = userInfo[created] as? String ?? ""
        print("created:::", CreatedDate ?? "")

     }

          window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
             let homeViewController = ViewController()
             homeViewController.Body = Body
             homeViewController.CreatedDate = CreatedDate
             homeViewController.FormKey = FormKey
             homeViewController.processDefinitionName = processDefinitionName
             homeViewController.ProcessInstanceId = ProcessInstanceId
             homeViewController.TaskID = TaskID
             homeViewController.Title = Title
             homeViewController.Types = Types
             homeViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
             window!.rootViewController = homeViewController
             window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


      completionHandler()
    
    
  }
```

Here is the code viewController from the app side, it will load the framework viewController method.

**Attempt 1:**

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    let controller = CreateCardViewController()
        let str = FormKey
        let result = String(str?.dropFirst(7) ?? "")
        print(result)
        let s = String(result.dropLast(10))
        print("newFormKey call form view", s )
        let v = convap(text: s)
        controller.processInstanceId = ProcessInstanceId
        controller.cardName = ""
        controller.TaskIdValue = TaskID
        controller.formKey = v
        controller.tabName = "NotificationTapped"
        print(controller.tabName)
        controller.fullFormKey = FormKey
    add(asChildViewController: controller)
    
        
    }


      private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChild(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
   }
```

**Attempt: 2**

```
      override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

                print("Presenting next...")
     
    
    let controller = CreateCardViewController()


            let str = FormKey
            let result = String(str?.dropFirst(7) ?? "")
            print(result)
            let s = String(result.dropLast(10))
            print("newFormKey call form view", s )
            let v = convap(text: s)
            controller.processInstanceId = ProcessInstanceId
            controller.cardName = ""
            controller.TaskIdValue = TaskID
            controller.formKey = v
            controller.tabName = "NotificationTapped"
            print(controller.tabName)
            controller.fullFormKey = FormKey

         present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

Any help much appreciated pls...

Answer (score 0):

I have such task currently maybe it is a little bit simpler but this is my code:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if let navigationController =  window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        if let someViewController = navigationController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as? SomeViewController {
            navigationController.pushViewController(someViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, it works fine because I have UINavigationController as a root of my app, and I manage my navigation through it. This is important to be sure what you have on your stack of views right now and how to clear it.

Also, you can see that I use this line for instantiating my new ViewController

```
if let someViewController = navigationController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeViewController") as? SomeViewController
```

But this is not important, just be sure that your ViewController is correctly initiated.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I used the top view controller to present the desired view.

To fetch top view controller:

```
func topController() -> UIViewController  {
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {

            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }
    return (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
}
```

Then on receiving notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
    guard Utility.shared.userInfo != nil else { return }

    let vc : EventDetailVC = EVENTSSTORYBOARD.viewController(id: "EventDetailVC") as! EventDetailVC
    vc.eventID = event_id
    vc.eventType = EventType.Invite
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.topController().present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NotificationCenter` create a custom `NSNotification.Name` and subscribe your viewcontroller to the created notification name  using

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(openView), name: <<custom notification name>>, object: nil)
```

after that using the selector function you can pass all the parameters to the view controller

```
@objc func openView(notification: Notification){}
```

and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` post to the above custom notification using this

```
let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]
            if (userInfo != nil){

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: <<custom notification name>>, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo as! [AnyHashable : Any]?)
                }
            }
```

if you have multiple viewcontrollers that needs to be open you can create a base view controller class and put above code in the base class and extend the viewcontrollers by the base class